# Would adding a method needed in a subclass to an abstract class break the Interface Segregation Principle?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, types, solid-principles

I have an abstract class called GameCharacter, that has some methods I'm gonna require from Game Characters.

There is another abstract class called Cell, that represents different types of cells and the operations associated to them.

Not every Cell is transitable, and I need to set a GameCharacter only for a subtype of Cell called GroundCell that is transitable.

My question is:

If I want to implement (in Cell):

`public abstract void setCharacter(GameCharacter character);`

...and only define its body to do something in GroundCell, and just leave it empty for the other subtypes of Cell... Would this break the Interface Segregation Principle, or any other SOLID Principle at all?

I have a bad smell about defining a method in the supertype for one specific class, but I don't want to use InstanceOf() because it breaks the Open-Closed Principle.

If this is not a practical solution, what would be one that wouldn't break the modular design?

Comment: Or you could have a `IsTransitable` interface on Cell and have GameCharacter set its position like `public abstract void setCell(IsTransitable cell);`. Or you could create an abstract TransitableCell that extends Cell.

Comment: It's the LSP you should worry about in this case rather than the ISP.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I'd be in the same situation, as I need to iterate through the collection of Cells anyways. I don't have a workaround yet, so I'd think what I'm doing it's the best solution, even if it looks a bit weird to leave empty function bodies.

Comment: @jaco0646 the LSP is certainly part of the deal, as it's related with the main subtyping problem, but following it, I certainly need the operation declared in the abstract class to be able to call it on any subtype there is. The problem is, code smells a bit when leaving empty-bodied functions.

Comment: Or you could consider having the character know where they are instead of the cell knowing what character(s) are present. Or have a third sort of "location tracker" class.

Comment: @JulianP The LSP is pretty much the same as avoid unexpected/unintuitive behaviors. What would you expect when calling `nonTransitableCell.setCharacter(character)`. If it fails silently without anything in the interface telling me it might fail or not be supported then I'd be wondering why it works for cell1 and not for cell2. If you had `public void setCharacter(character) throws NotTransitableException` it's already a little better (or just `IllegalStateException`). It could also return a boolean value to let you know whether or not it accepted.

Comment: Other strategies would be to use the ISP and maintain a `Set<Transitable> transitableCells` reference, implement a concept such as `TransitivityStrategy whenMovedOn(Movable movable)` or something like that where you'd have `NonTransitable implements TransitivityStrategy`, etc.

Comment: @plalx Amazing response. That’s the approach I wanted to take but I wasn’t sure about declaring an exception for a method that shouldn’t be there in the first place, but you make a good point on abstracting the knowledge to the client, it’s nice to be able to let the user try to set it without knowing it’s able or not, then handling the exception as needed.